# Pass Session Table output as out parameter in db2 stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a requirement where I want to pass one of my session/ Global Temporary Table as output value from DB2 stored procedure to Java.

[The procedure is being called by Java and hence the output of procedure[whole session table data] needs to be passed on the Java application.

Is this possible in Db2. If so can you give some example.

Answer (score 2):

Note: DB2 has the concept of providing [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG) to its users. It includes a search function. When putting in "procedure table result sql java" it brings up useful documentation.

[DB2 can return result sets from within procedures back to the caller](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009166.html). This is done through cursors. The keyword to look for is `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS`